# Order By month and Year for 2 columns in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, date

Employee table is listed below...

```
    Name          DOJ                  DOL
 ............   ...............      ............
    Ram            2014-01-12          2014-02-12
    Kiran          2014-02-05          2014-07-05
    Jhon           2014-01-25          2014-10-01
```

Expected Output is....

```
    Month          Joining_count     Leaving_count
  ...........     ................  .................
   Jan-2014              2                 0
   Feb-2014              1                 1
      .                  .                 .
      .                  .                 .
      .                  .                 .
```

I tried with below Mysql Query but i am not able get expected output
please help me

```
        SELECT monthname(current_date) as month, 

        count( `DATE_OF_JOINING`)  as 'Joining_count' , 
        count( `DATE_OF_LEAVING`)  as 'leaving_count' , 

        group by year(`DATE_OF_JOINING`),month('DATE_OF_JOINING`),
        year(`DATE_OF_LEAVING),month(`DATE_OF_LEAVING)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are performing two different aggregations on the same data - so you'd need two aggregate queries `join`ed.
Unfortunately, [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) doesn't have a full outer join, so it's a bit of a hassle to handle both months where someone left but nobody joined and months somebody joined by nobody left. I solves this with three joins - one query to get all the possible dates, and another two for each aggregation, although [there are other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/full-outer-join-in-mysql).

```
SELECT    my_table.d, COALESCE(join_count, 0), COALESCE(leave_count, 0)
FROM      (SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(doj, '%b-%y') AS d
           FROM   my_table
           UNION
           SELECT DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(dol, '%b-%y')
           FROM   my_table) dates
LEFT JOIN (SELECT   DATE_FORMAT(doj, '%b-%y') d, COUNT(*) AS join_count
           FROM     my_table
           GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(doj, '%b-%y')
          ) joins ON dates.d = joins.d
LEFT JOIN (SELECT   DATE_FORMAT(dol, '%b-%y') d, COUNT(*) AS leave_count
           FROM     my_table
           GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(dol, '%b-%y')
          ) leaves ON dates.d = leaves.d
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need two queries, one for grouping the joining dates and one for the leaving dates. You can combine both results using `UNION ALL` and treat the combined result as a new table and select (and `SUM`) the values then.

```
SELECT 
  s.month, 
  SUM(s.Joining_count) AS Joining_count, 
  SUM(s.Leaving_count) AS Leaving_count
FROM
  (
   SELECT 
     DATE_FORMAT(doj, '%b-%y') as `month`, 
     COUNT(ej.doj)  as 'Joining_count',
     0 AS 'Leaving_count'
   FROM employee ej
     GROUP BY `month`

   UNION ALL

   SELECT 
     DATE_FORMAT(dol, '%b-%y') as `month`, 
     0  as 'Joining_count',
     COUNT(el.dol)  as 'Leaving_count'  
   FROM employee el
     GROUP BY `month`
  ) s
GROUP BY s.`month`;
```

Output will be

```
month       Joining_count   Leaving_count
---------------------------------------------
Feb-2014    1               1
Jan-2014    2               0
Jul-2014    0               1
Oct-2014    0               1
```